# How can I get rid of the gap between the two colliders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

Although each collider was created on two objects, the collision check was not smooth because the collider of the two objects was separated. How can I get rid of the gap between colliders?

I tried it, but it was reduced and the gap was not removed

Comment: "A picture is worth a thousand words." Do you have any? I'm having a hard time visualizing your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the character controller skin width to 0.08 (default value) may work and remove the collider spacing between the two objects.